# What sources are there saying that the knot of the tefillah shel yad should be right next to the bayit?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilin

I know that the Zohar brings that the yud knot of the tefillin should rest right next to the titura (box), but are there other sources which do not rule al pi kabbalah?

Comment: Where does the Zohar rule this way?

Comment: You mean davkaa the tetura or the ketzitzah as well

Comment: The titura, I have seen examples of retzuot that have not touched the ketzitzah, even when fastened with a kesher Chofetz Chaim.

Answer (score 3):

The [Shulchan Aruch 27:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=72) writes one should be careful that the knot should not move from the teffilin. The Mishna Brurah brings the Zohar who says one should be extra careful that the yud does not move.He brings an opinion even when not worn it shouldn't be moved away from the box and some use a gid(sinew) to keep it in place.

(י) יש ליזהר - ובזוהר פ' פנחס מחמיר מאוד בענין זה ויש מחמירין דגם כשהן בתוך כיסן צריכין ליזהר בזה שלא תזוז כלל היו"ד ומטעם זה יש נוהגין לקשור היו"ד עם חוט של גיד עם התפלה וראוי לבטל זה דע"י הקשירה יהיה חוט של גיד סביב התיתורא חוצץ בין הזרוע להתפילין ובלבושי שרד כתב דראוי לבטל ג"כ המנהג שכורכין הרצועה במקום הקיבורת תחת התיתורא דהוי ג"כ חציצה

Comment: Where does the B"Y get this from, also, what do Rama and Tur say?

Comment: You don't have access to one?

Comment: Not really, I don't.